# jquery adding to the last tr of the first table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table structure like the one shown below:

```
<table id="result">
<tr>
<td id="groupx">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to add a TD to the last tr of table result. Trying `x.appendTo($("#result tr:last"));`
isn't working since it's adding to the last tr of a table id "group"

Any sugestions on how I can keep using this structure of html and do this?

Comment: Why are you nesting tables in the first place? I can count on one hand the number of times I've seen that end well, though of course I don't know what your particular reasons are.

Comment: You haven't closed your table properly in td#groupx. Is this a typo just in the question? Check your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Nadia's answer was almost good, it missed one thing: browsers put all direct `tr` childs of a `table` into a `tbody` element, so this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lol</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

gets translated internally to this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lol</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So all you need to do is this:

```
x.appendTo($("#result>tbody>tr:last"));
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: This was the same answer that I was about to put. It was just a matter of getting the right selector.